# Regex to allow number between 1-18 with decimal values

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write regex which allow only number between 1-18 with decimal value.
Below expression allow 18.10 - 18.99 .Please suggest if any.
Thanks in advance

```
((?:[1-9]|1[0-8])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|18(?:\.00?)?)$
```

Comment: You want values from 1.00 - 18.00 only with 2 decimal places?

Comment: yes , you are right @Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is basically fine, you just need to change `[0-8]` to `[0-7]` to not allow any values starting with `18` other than `18.0` or `18.00`, and you should escape the `.` characters to force them to match only a `.`. Finally you should anchor the match to the beginning of the string as well as the end:

```
^((?:[1-9]|1[0-7])(?:\.\d{1,2})?|18(?:\.00?)?)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EPtx25/1)
[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/q0I00)